# Output element with the greatest value in certain position. Python

Tags: python, append, max, output

what I am trying to do here is **append** the element form **the_list** with the **greatest value**

in the **[-1]** position . i started by creating an index dictionary for the elements in the_list but i started to get lost in the logic flow.

```
the_list = [['a','b','c','1'],['b','c','e','4'],['d','e','f','2']]
D_indx_element = {}
D_indx_value = {}
output = []

temp = []
for i,k in zip(range(0,len(the_list)),the_list):
    D_indx_element[i] = k
    temp.append(int(k[-1]))
    D_indx_value[i] = int(k[-1])
```

in the end i would like to have:

```
output = [['b','c','e','4']]
```

since 4 is greater than 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max`:

```
>>> the_list = [['a','b','c','1'],['b','c','e','4'],['d','e','f','2']]
>>> max(the_list, key=lambda x:int(x[-1]))
['b', 'c', 'e', '4']
```

Without `lambda`:

```
def func(x):
    return int(x[-1])
max(the_list, key=func)
#['b', 'c', 'e', '4']
```

Comment: hey do you by chance know of a good source to figure out what Lambda actually is doing besides the official documentation? I always see it in people's codes and it seems like a one line function type thing but i can't actually explain what it is to someone else

Comment: @draconisthe0ry http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html

Comment: @draconisthe0ry - `lambda` makes an inline function.  It is no different than `def`, except that it can be used where `def` can't (as in the example above).  Here is a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/python-lambda-why.  Truth be told, Python can do just fine without `lambda`--it is simply syntax sugar.  ;)